# Modify file in storage account using Azure Powershell Function App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell

I'm using a Logic App to transform a CSV file to an XML file, but currently the output is all in a single line.  So I'm thinking maybe I could create a function app to open up the file, [xml] it and save the file in the hope it will beautify it, basically something like this:

```
$xml = [xml] (gc "filelocation")
$xml.Save("filelocation")
```

When I created the function app (called ParseXML) it already has a default powershell code:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

How do I modify this code and the Logic App to attempt to do what I want, I imagine I first need to create parameters in the powershell script to define where my file is and what it's called, which I can get from the Logic App:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer required because it turns out there is an extra setting within the logic app which is not set by default, simply set Apply XSLT output attributes and the job's a good'un:

[image]